# Block a function/button if they exceed maximum attempts

Tags: java, android

In my code, I'm only manage to direct user to the main page if they fail to authenticate themselves by exceeding the maximum attempts and apparently it is not effective if the user still can access to the authentication page and carry on with the attempts until they successfully authenticate themselves.

```
    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {

    //Add one to the number of attempts taken
    attemptCount += 1;

    if (attemptCount < maxAttemptAllowance) {
        super.onAuthenticationFailed();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Fingerprint Authentication Failed, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        //here is where the system block user if they exceed the maximum attempts
        Toast.makeText(context, "Exceed maximum attempts, try again in 5 minutes later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        context.startActivity((new Intent(context, Main.class)));
    }
}
```

So here is my question, is there is anyway i could block/restrict/disable a function but not the entire system for 5 minutes if the user exceed the maximum attempts.

Thanks in advance if u guys willing to suggest me a way as I really don't have the idea/logic for this problem

Answer (score 1):

Store the condition in a SharedPreference along with the current time, so that even if the app is closed the value persists. That is a better option to do things like this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example of delay. It will hide(you can modify as you need) the button and shows the remaining time to appear it again.

```
private CountDownTimer delay_timer;
public void Delay_Timer(final int length){

    int min;
    Log.e("Delay timer"," Running ");
    delay_timer = new CountDownTimer(length*1000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.e("Delay timer"," onTick "+"" +(millisUntilFinished / 1000)+ " Seconds remaining.");
            if(delay!=null) delay.setText("Button will be Enabled in "+SecToMin(millisUntilFinished / 1000)+" sec.");
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            enable_next();
        }

    };
    try{
        disable_next();
        delay_timer.start();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("Delay excpt"," "+ex.getMessage());
        enable_next();
    }
}

private String SecToMin(long totalSecs){
    long hours = totalSecs / 3600;
    long minutes = (totalSecs % 3600) / 60;
    long seconds = totalSecs % 60;

    String timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    return timeString;
}

public void Stop_recording_timer(){
    delay_timer.cancel();
}

private void enable_next(){
    if(submit!=null){
        delay.setText("");
        submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private void disable_next(){
    if(submit!=null){
        submit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

now when your attempt exceeds call.

```
   if(exceeds){
     Delay_Timer(time_in_secs);
   }
```